# UIScrollView with Autolayout in InterfaceBuilder

Tags: uiscrollview, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm trying to use a UIScrollView with autolayout. I simply cannot make it work the way it works with struts and springs. I want to use autolayout as that's the way ahead but it is so frustrating that Apple just put a tiny document and even that does not explain this in detail.
I would like to state that I'm using IB and not making my view in code (that's just not an option these days).

This is my view hierarchy:

```
-UIViewController

    -UIView (the base view)

        -UIScrollView [Contraints: topEdge-SuperView-0, leftEdge-SuperView-0, bottomEdge-SuperView (bottom layout guide sometimes)-0, rightEdge-SuperView-0, and sometimes CenterX-Superview-0]

            -UIView (the content View) [topEdge-SuperView-0, leftEdge-SuperView-0, bottomEdge-SuperView-0, rightEdge-SuperView-0, and also tried CenterX and centerY seperately]

                -The Actual Content [Constrained to the super view]
```

I think this is what Apple calls a pure Autolayout setup with UIScrollView and Autolayout according to their documentation. Please do not refer me to that document, I have read it like a number of times. Now I also go ahead and do the

```
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO
```

but the result is same, with or without the above option being true or false.

The Result: Nothing Scrolls...!!

Is there a method to this madness? I've tried to duplicate what rmayoff did in his video cast on Youtube (please do not refer me to that either), but nope... nothing..!!